# How can I remove milliseconds from Timestamp in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I want to export data from 'My_Customer' table in .csv format.
I am extracting a time field but I am getting the output along with Milliseconds.
Eg:
The output I am getting,
`25-10-2017 12:53:12:00076`
I want to remove/truncate the milliseconds.

Expected Output-
`25-10-2017 12:53:12`.

I have tried `to_char()` but it isn't giving proper output. (Instead of giving the exact time available in that field, it is `rounding off`).

Comment: Why don't you share the result of what you tried and what didn't work? TO_CHAR() should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your timestamp to a character string:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS my_date
  FROM DUAL;

MY_DATE
-----------------------------
2017-OCT-13 00:38:26
```

Comment: Such questions was already answered very well and iterating same thing doesnot make sense. Feel free to mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You can either cast it to a timestamp with no fractional seconds (this will round to the nearest second):

```
CAST( your_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP(0) )
```

Or to a `DATE` data type (this will truncate to the nearest second):

```
CAST( your_timestamp AS DATE )
```

Or you can convert it to a formatted string and specify the format model you want to use (this will truncate to the nearest second):

```
TO_CHAR( your_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7db4ac/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_timestamp ) AS
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-25 12:53:12.10076' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CAST( your_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP(0) ) AS "Timestamp",
       CAST( your_timestamp AS DATE ) AS "Date",
       TO_CHAR( your_timestamp, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS "String"
FROM   your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7db4ac/2/0)**:

```
|             Timestamp |                 Date |              String |
|-----------------------|----------------------|---------------------|
| 2017-10-25 12:53:12.0 | 2017-10-25T12:53:12Z | 25-10-2017 12:53:12 |
```

How the `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` are formatted will depend on your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` and `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameters but you can directly control the formatting of `TO_CHAR` when you specify a format model.

Comment: Such questions was already answered very well and iterating same thing doesnot make sense. Feel free to mark it duplicate.

Comment: How to use cast() in stored procedure?